# bootstrap modal remote content error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 different files the index.php, register.php and login.php. In the index.php there is an anchor that will show the modal with remote content from login.php which works perfectly, and in login.php there is an option that will change the content of the modal which load remotely from register.php but when I click it, it show's javascript error in the console.

console error  : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function   bootstrap.js:868`

**I am using jquery 1.10.1 and bootstrap 3.1.1**

index.php

```
<script src="common/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="common/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>   

<div class="account_link">
         <a href="login.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog">Sign In</a>
       </div>
      <div id="dialog" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" area-  hidden="true" aria-labelledby="signin">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" style="width:320px">

         </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

login.php

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form name="signin" method="post">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="signin">Sign In</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="login_control clearfix">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="textfield"/>
        </div>
        <div class="login_control clearfix">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="textfield"/>
        </div>
        <p><input type="checkbox"/><span>Remember me on this computer</span></p>
        Not a member? <a href="register.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialog">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Forgot Password</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="login_btn">Sign In</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

register.php

```
    <html>
  <head></head>
  <title>Create Account</title>
  <body>
    <form method="post" name="frm-signup">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="signin">Sign In</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="textfield" name="reg_email" placeholder="Email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="textfield" name="reg_fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <label>Confirm Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="textfield" name="reg_fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="clearfix">
          <button type="submit" name="sign-up">Create Account</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you included jquery before the bootstrap js file?

Comment: Yes. I included the jquery first then next is the bootstrap.js file. Please see it edited. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call a second modal from the first modal if the first is itself remote.

If you think about it, bootstrap's js will be looking through your DOM when the page is loaded. It will spot your modal anchor and it will attach an event.

However when that event fires, and the remote content is loaded (i.e. login.php is displayed), bootstrap won't go through the new DOM again looking for new modal anchors to which it can attach new events.

You might be better off doing this in your own JS, using the `.modal()` function in the bootstrap API, and attaching your events after login.php is displayed.

You've probably already read the relevant documentation but [here is a link to it anyway](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), just in case!

Comment: I see. I think I misunderstand the bootstrap. Can you provide me an example on how can I achieve this?